# How to auto-increment a list of const values in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

For example, how would I do something similar to the following, where all the values are unique:

```
private var id = 0
const val id0 = id++ // Gives error: "Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value"
const val id1 = id++
const val idasdf = id++
const val idqwerty = id++
// Many more rows (sometimes 10s, potentially 1000s?), with random vals being added and removed occasionally
```

I would strongly prefer to use this way of setting many constants because it would look cleaner and when I add/remove random values, I don't have to worry about any uniqueness issues (it's okay for the values to change between builds, and the values don't need to be consecutive). (And, vals are added so that the list of them are in alphabetical order)

Workarounds that I'm not really interested in:

- Using Java `static final`
- Manually setting values
- Using something like `const val idasdf = "asdf".hashcode()` also doesn't work for the same reason as using `... = i++`
- Removing `const`, aka just using `val id1 = i++` (because I want to learn more Kotlin or maybe another design pattern)

Sidenote: A long time ago floats and doubles couldn't be set as const in Kotlin, but they updated that. So, maybe (hopefully) this is in their backlog too? But, I haven't found it yet after a quick search.

ps: I'm working in Android. Maybe this note can expand the number of possible workarounds, like using `IntDef`

Comment: Kotlin is correct. `const val` is exclusively for values known at *compile time*. Your `const val` is computed based on the value of a `private var` (i.e. a runtime mutable value). If your goal is to make it so the value can't be reassigned, then `val` already does that, so there's no need for the `const`.

Comment: "when I add/remove random values, I don't have to worry about any uniqueness issues" - actually, this is a very bad idea. Consts are meant to be fixed. Imagine you have `FOO = 3` in your code and someone used it as a library. Then their library is used with newer version of your lib where `FOO = 4`, but their code still points at `3`, so e.g. `BAR`. And of course the same may happen in your own project if you split it into modules (but this is less probable).  By changing the value of `const val` you actually make a binary incompatible change.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, I agree, Kotlin is right. Theoretically, with the current Kotlin constructs, that mutable var could be changed in another thread between those `const val` lines.

@broot, yep, good call out! I added a note in the question about my use case: "it's okay for the values to change between builds" ;)

Comment: @broot Not every module is a library and not every constant is public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition a `const` is a value known at compile time. It is inlined as a hard-coded value at every usage site, so it cannot be initialized at runtime like this, and this pattern never will be possible unless they come up with some mechanism for incrementing a compile-time-only variable.

To get something that compiles like a Java static final field, use `@JvmField`.

```
private var id = 0
@JvmField val id0 = id++
@JvmField val id1 = id++
@JvmField val idasdf = id++
@JvmField val idqwerty = id++
```

There's not a lot of advantage here over simply using `val` though. I suppose it prevents a getter method from being generated. What are you hoping to gain by marking them `const`?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `@JvmField`! Yeah, I thought about putting a little more background in my question related to Android, and the generated getters, and limited method count (workarounds available). But, easiest way to explain my goal is that I'm trying to learn more, even if the savings are negligible from the user perspective. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but your requirements — a series of compile-time constants with consecutive integer values starting from 0 — look rather like an `enum`.

Would an `enum class` work in your case? The compiler assigns an integer value to each, which you can access with the `ordinal` field:

```
enum class Colour { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE }

fun main() {
    println(RED.ordinal)    // prints 0
    println(ORANGE.ordinal) // prints 1
}
```

Comment: yep, happy you noticed, enums would absolutely work for the stated use case! If I wasn't working with mobile/Android, then I may have chosen to do this. (I didn't tag as 'Android' because I didn't want to limit answers to that)

Similarly, the memory-efficient version of this is to use `IntDef`: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/IntDef

Sidenote: Doesn't need to be consecutive, just unique.

Answer (score 1):

`const` means "compile time constant". You cannot use the keyword `const` for a value that isn't known at compile time.